# How can I use debounce with initialValue in React-Final-Form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-final-form

I need to use `debounce` on input `onChange`, but I also need the value from the form's `initialValues`. On adding debounce with `value={props.value}` nothing happens in the textbox on typing which is expected as `props.value` get updated after the debounce timer. But what is the solution for this?

```
  const debounced = debounce(e => {
    input.onChange(e);
  }, 500);

  <FormControl
    value={input.value}
    onChange={e => {
      e.persist();
      debounced(e);
    }}
  />
```

In the above case, nothing gets typed in the input box.
And if I don't pass `value` prop, I don't get my existing value auto-populated in the input box.

Would love to get suggestions on how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you **need** to use `debounce`? Maybe the actual solution is to use a debounce elsewhere (other than in the component). Are you making an API call? I'm guessing the correct solution is to debounce the API call rather than the input event.

Comment: No, I'm not making any API call, it's just I have a form with many fields and FormSpy(React-final-form)'s onChange recreates my entire form every time I type something in my input box. So I was trying to avoid this by adding debounce on onChange handler.

Comment: Were you seeing any logical errors or performance issues when you weren't using debounce?

Comment: By the way, if you are seeing performance issues, then you aren't using final-form correctly. Final form is designed to be wickedly fast - you're probably just using a `Spy` in the wrong place. You should **never** need `debounce` with final form.

Answer (score -1):

The following should debounce the input and update the state accordingly.

```js
const { useState } = React;

const debounce = (callback, wait) => {
  let timeoutId = null;
  return (...args) => {
    window.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    timeoutId = window.setTimeout(() => {
      callback.apply(null, args);
    }, wait);
  };
}

const App = () => {
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState('');
  
  const handleChange = debounce(e => setCurrent(e.target.value), 500);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <input type="text" onChange={handleChange} />
        <p>{current}</p>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('react'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: You failed to factor the initial value

Comment: @AviE.Koenig what is the initial value?